# After saving stylesheet the changes aren't picked up by site

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, notepad++, filezilla

I just occured a very strange problem.
When I edit my stylesheet and save it (with ftp filezilla) and I refresh the page with Ctrl-f5, there are no changes in the style.

When I make a new stylesheet and copy the code from the 'not working' stylesheet into there and save with the new name it works. but when I edit that stylesheet, the same problem appears.

I really don't know what te problem is.

I use

- Notepad++
- filezilla FTP client
- Chrome webbrowser

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache?

Comment: Sometimes server caches files also, review the configuration or try restarting the server to clear the cache

Comment: Clear browser cache. Or use a different browser if you're skeptical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a common caching problem. One way to solve it is by adding a version parameter to the stylesheet’s URL:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.example.com/css/style.css?v=1.1" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Just increment the version number (the `v` param in the URL), this will force the browser to download the file as it will be considered "new"/different.

Comment: +1 as this is the most headache-free method of cache busting.

Comment: @KeesSonnema It's not a bug. Browsers and proxys cache files such as css and js files to make everyone's browsing experience better. Adding a query string and changing it when the file is updated simply forces a recaching of the relevant file. A more automated method might be to add some code to the query string which attaches the modified date e.g. in php: href="css/style.css?date=<? if (file_exists('css/style.css')) {echo filemtime('css/style.css');}?>" will add the modified date to the query string and doesn't need amending when the file changes.